# Tizen is unable to record audio in real time

Tags: audio, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I follow the [audio i/o tutorial](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.tutorials/html/native/multimedia/audio_io_tutorial_n.htm) to build a real-time audio recording app. However, the callback is called very infrequently for recording the whole sound. For example, when I start the recording for 5 second, the callback actually only gives a 2-second clip (instead of 5).

Here is a dummy testing code which only dumps how many bytes have been recorded:

```
int _audio_read_total;
static void _audio_io_stream_read_cb(audio_in_h handle, size_t nbytes, void *userdata)
{
    const void *buffer = NULL;
    if (nbytes > 0) {
        int error_code = audio_in_peek(handle, &buffer, &nbytes);
        _audio_read_total += nbytes;
        dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "nbytes = %d,_audio_read_total = %d", nbytes, _audio_read_total);
        error_code = audio_in_drop(handle); // remove audio data from internal buffer
    }
}
static void start_audio_recording(appdata_s *ad)
{
    int error_code = audio_in_create(48000, AUDIO_CHANNEL_MONO, AUDIO_SAMPLE_TYPE_S16_LE, &ad->input);    
    error_code = audio_in_set_stream_cb(ad->input, _audio_io_stream_read_cb, ad);
    error_code = audio_in_prepare(ad->input);
}
```

[image: start]
[image: end (5 seconds later)]
Attached images include the result of running this code on Galaxy Gear S3. As you can see in the image, the recording callback is called from time 32.3 to time 37.7 (over 5 seconds), but only 224250 bytes are received (it should be (37.7-32.3)*48000*sizeof(short) = 518400). That means only less than 40% of audio is recorded.

Could anyone give me some suggestions to solve this issue?

Yu-Chih

Comment: You may go through the solution in this link( https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/recording-audio-io-callback-very-slow-only-pick-up-less-45-audio ).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use

```
int audio_in_set_interrupted_cb (   audio_in_h  input,
audio_io_interrupted_cb     callback,
void *  user_data 
)
```

Registers a callback function to be invoked when the audio input handle is interrupted or the interrupt is completed. I will explore further and try to reproduce this.